# Access Shell32.dll string table from a command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, shell32.dll

I'm a making a simple Win32 batch to perform some tasks. One of them is to add "open prompt here" in every directory. Reading around I learned that you can use Shell32.dll string to table to use its string with regedit, for example this is my batch test.

```
echo Adding <need string here> to folders
REG ADD HKCR\Directory\Shell\Open.MSDOS /ve /f /d "@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-22022"
REG ADD HKCR\Directory\Shell\Open.MSDOS\command /ve /f /d "cmd.exe /K \"pushd \"%%1\"\""
```

my question is: How can I extract the string for shell32.dll so the user can see the output like this (Spanish):

```
Adding Símbolo del sistema to folders
```

Comment: Do you mean the same as _Open command window here_, appearing when _Shift_ + double-clicking a folder in Windows Explorer?

Comment: yes, I want to grab the string and output it in the console from my batch file.

Comment: @Joel How can a resource have a negative index (-22022)? My experience with creating resources with rc file says that resources are always non-negative

Comment: @SahilSingh The data for a language-neutral registry value has the format "@<PE-path>,-<stringID>[;<comment>]". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-registry-string-redirection